# Manually setting user_id when extending User in Django 1.5?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I'me extendig the auth `User` model with additional fields.

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    .... #other fields#
```

I create them in the following way.

```
base_user = User(username =  'username', password = 'password', email = 'user@mail.com')
extended_user = ExtendedUser(user = base_user, ...#other fields#)
```

In that scenario the `user_id` is not set. If I try to save the base_user to the database an error occures.

```
extended_user.save()
#Exception traceback
... user_id may not be NULL
```

What bothers me is that I the following solves the problem:

```
extended_user.user_id = extended_user.user.id
```

This was done automatically for my custom OneToOne relations. Am I missing something regarding the `User` or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the `base_user` first for it to have an `pk` (it's generated by the database).

```
base_user = User(username =  'username', password = 'password', email = 'user@mail.com')
assert base_user.pk is None  # Of course that's not required, just here to prove the point.
base_user.save()
extended_user = ExtendedUser(user = base_user, ...#other fields#)
```

But even better,

```
base_user = User.objects.create(username= 'username', password='password', email='user@mail.com')
extended_user = ExtendedUser.objects.create(user=base_user, #...)
```